# Outlook calendar (Small calender view) is not showing dates in Bold when there is an appointment

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm having a little problem in my Outlook 2010 over Exchange 2010 (Windows 7 Enterprise). When I go in my Outlook calendar and then I see the calendar's day, sorted by month (Not the whole big calendar's view), none of the dates with activities are bolded. 
[image]

On another PC, I created my account in Outlook and it worked.

I tried some Outlook switches with no luck

- Cleanfreebusy
- Resetfolders

Also deleted custom forms, rebooted PC and Outlook but no luck.

Any help will be welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your appointments' `Show time as` option is set to `Free`.
Edit the appointment or right-click on an appointment and choose `Show time as` or `Show as` and choose any of the following options from the sub-menu:

**1.Tentative

2.Busy

3.Out of Office**

Now immediately date will be changed **BOLD**.

[image]

Appointment set to **Show as Free**
[image]

Same Appointment set to **Show as Busy**
[image]

Comment: nice illustration

Comment: Great answer, perfectly demonstrated! You deserve those points! Thank you!

Comment: Nice answer, but unfortunately in Outlook 365 it doesn't seem to work any longer.